# Change wifi password of in raspberry pi

Tags: networking, 22.04, raspberrypi

I have setup wifi on my raspberry pi ubuntu 22.04 system. But now I want to change password of my wifi.
When I look into netplan file '50-cloud-init.yaml', It says following in comment :

```bash
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
```

How to change password from where this file is getting generated?
Please note, I don't want to disable auto updation of this file, but I want to edit the source from where this file is getting updated.

Comment: you're using cloud-init, that means that the source of boot info is providing this info, and it needs to be changed there. Unless you're not using cloud-init, in which case why are you using the cloud-init.yaml file?

Comment: @Esther I have just installed ubuntu on raspberry pi, so whatever is default is used by it. If it is being updated by cloud-init, where I can modify it to use different username password?

Comment: to be clear, you're looking to change the password the raspberry pi is using to connect to your wifi? Or to change *its own* wifi password (if it's acting as a wireless access point)?

Comment: if you're not using cloud-init, then you don't have to worry about the file being overwritten, because there is nothing that can overwrite it. Just make the changes there (or make a new file called `51-my-config.yaml` or whatever, it's the number that counts: higher number = higher priority ) and put the configs there. You can also disable cloud network config in the file specified since you aren't using that service at all anyways.